# How to create an empty repository with no files or folders?

Tags: github

I'm trying to create an empty repo with no files or branches in them with no commits or commit messages. Just an empty repo. I tried to add gitignores and gitkeeps but they still show commit messages and branches. How do I create one like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you creating it online, or on the desktop app?

Comment: using terminal. command line tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in to GitHub online; and when you create a new repository, simply DON'T ADD ENYTHING TO IT.  Comes out like what you want:

[image]

If an empty repo is what you need, that's how you do it...

Comment: Thanks. I had to log out to to able to see it this way.

Comment: Oh...  Yeah..  Should've mentioned that.  When you're logged in, it just keeps asking you to put stuff in it...  Damn GitHub...  So needy and demanding.